# React Typescript: property 'body' does not exist type 'DefaultTheme'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am new to React and Typescript, I am trying to add dark-mode to my project,
I created globalStyle component, Themes component and using Themeprovider.

I am facing an issue on my globalStyle component when it says:
property 'body' does not exist type 'DefaultTheme'

My globalStyles.tsx code is as follow:

```
import { createGlobalStyle} from "styled-components"
export const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.body};
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.text};
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Roboto, sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.50s linear;
  }`
```

my Themes.tsx:

```
export const lightTheme = {
    body: '#FFF',
    text: '#363537',
    background: '#363537',
}
export const darkTheme = {
    body: '#363537',
    text: '#FAFAFA',
    background: '#999',
}
```

and my Themeprovider code on App.tsx:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={this.state.theme === 'light' ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
        <>
        <GlobalStyles/>
            <ul className='tickets'>
                {filteredTickets.map((ticket) => (
                <li key={ticket.id} className={ticket.toggle ? 'expand' : 'ticket'}>
                    <h5 className='title'>{ticket.title}</h5>
                    <button onClick={() => this.onHide(ticket.id)}>Hide</button>
                    <p className={ticket.toggle ? 'show-more' : 'content'}>{ticket.content}</p>
                    <button onClick={()=> this.onToggle(ticket.id)}>{ticket.toggle ? 'Show less' : 'Show more'}</button>
                    <footer>
                        <div className='meta-data'>By {ticket.userEmail} | { new Date(ticket.creationTime).toLocaleString()}</div>
                    </footer>
                </li>))}
            </ul>
        </>
        </ThemeProvider>
```

What am I doing wrong and why theme.body and theme.text is not recognized on globalStyles.tsx?

Thanks !

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: please consider my answer below.

Answer (score 19):

I'm basing this answer on the following link: [https://spectrum.chat/styled-components/general/i-cant-use-my-theme-in-createglobalstyle-function-styled-components-v4-react-v16-6-3~0978b404-ab71-45c9-8f75-0862abde4eb5](https://spectrum.chat/styled-components/general/i-cant-use-my-theme-in-createglobalstyle-function-styled-components-v4-react-v16-6-3%7E0978b404-ab71-45c9-8f75-0862abde4eb5)

`createGlobalStyle` can accept a shape for the theme:

```
createGlobalStyle<{theme: ThemeType}>
```

From the `styled-components` docs, there's this (https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript):

```
declare module 'styled-components' {
  export interface DefaultTheme {
    borderRadius: string;

    colors: {
      main: string;
      secondary: string;
    };
  }
}
```

So, I suggest you set up an interface for your theme, as above, and then pass it into `createGlobalStyle` in place of `ThemeType`

Comment: if you have issue exporting `ThemeType` with above way then use this `export type ThemeType = typeof theme;` ref : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28481

Comment: I have to downvote this because useTheme delivers an object typed as Default Theme regardless of what the object actually contains and regardless of what you type createGlobalStyle.

I will look for a real solution and post a comment if I find one.

Comment: The Spectrum example helped me solve my issue. I was using Material-UI's theme with Styled-Components' createGlobalStyle, in case anyone is having the same issue. In my case, `palette` did not exist on `DefaultTheme`. 

` color: ${({ theme }) => `${theme.palette.grey[600]}`};`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `styled-components` docs (https://styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) I created an interface for the body type:

```
export interface DefaultTheme {
  body: string;
}

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle<{ theme: DefaultTheme }>`

body{
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.body};
  color: var(--font-color);
}

`;
```

This works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer above fails, as useTheme does not know what type you passed to createGlobalStyles.

But this is a typescript workaround that doesn't require you to use ts-ginore:

1. As jnpdx suggested, you do need to type the createGlobalTheme object:

`createGlobalStyle<{theme: ThemeType}>`

2. The only working solution I have figured out so far is to post-type your useTheme variable like so:

`const theme = useTheme() as ThemeType;`

Comment: Thanks, this solution work for me ! The problem was not with the styled-module but with the useTheme itself !